# When inspecting an element in Chrome Devtools, what does the blue arrow signify?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Anyone who is an "expert" at Chrome Devtools should be able to explain **what does the blue arrow signify?**

Here is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68863567/what-does-the-skewed-dash-area-mean-in-chrome-devtools-when-inspecting-an-elemen) that has been unanswered about what the hash means.

[image]

Comment: The arrow shows if the item grew or shrank.

Comment: From flex? What would cause an element to shrink?

Comment: Please add [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Pretty often the next html element is too wide, so it pushes left the element in the left side. You may want to try to change the container div size or decrease the width of the element on the left.